GeoJSON in Apache Superset's "deck.gl geojson" graph scal badly
I have a question regarding GeoJSON using.
I've built a plot of "deck.gl geojson" type. My data contain lines and points (it is actually a route with stop points). I need to visualize them on map.
It works but with a problem: dots are too big. Superset allows to select size from the following list only (radius choosing).
Selection with point radius scale =100 looks like (enormous dots).
When i manually type there either 10 or even 99 or 101 - dots disappear, lines are kept only (radius=50).
In the json-file itself, it is selected like following:
'properties', jsonb_build_object(
'circle-radius', 15,
'marker-color', '#f00',
'marker-symbol', 'stop'
)
What can i do to reduce the size of these dots?
Thank you!
I tried changing format from "circle-radius" to "radius" in the json-file
"properties": {"radius": 15, "diff_time": -10, "fillColor": "#ff0000", "marker-symbol": "stop"}
And adding annotation to the graph - it is still not recognizable.
In the JavaScript console there are errors like this:
deck: drawing ScatterplotLayer({id: 'geojson-layer-277-points-circle'}) to screen: Uniform length cannot change. Error: Uniform length cannot change.
at r (assert.js:3:11)
at uniforms.js:226:7
at Z.setUniforms (program.js:203:13)
at C.draw (model.js:268:18)
at g.draw (scatterplot-layer.ts:270:8)
at layer.ts:1029:14
at W (unified-parameter-api.js:61:12)
at g._drawLayer (layer.ts:1021:7)
at kt._drawLayersInViewport (layers-pass.ts:236:17)
at kt._drawLayers (layers-pass.ts:99:28)


